# Longer bundle update install time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

Well, i took a break from RoR for studies, now I am back, I have noticed that it takes much longer to install gems, bundle update/install. Before I could complete the installation of a new gem in minutes now it takes hours and I have to force restart because I cant see any progress being made (Even with -V). Have tried reinstalling. No change. I can sucessfully ping the site in cmd, so it doesnt appear to be a firewall issue. Is this a problem that everyone is beginning to experience?

Apart from downloading the gems and installing locally/bundle update locally, is there any other way to speed this up? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Tried all the suggestions below but nothing so far :) thanks for the input and advice. One more thing I would like to add, is that I tried installing Ruby and Rails on a seperate computer and its working perfectly there. Any and all input is greatly appreciated.

UK

Comment: BTW, hours is not normal (by a wide margin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's taking more than a minute or so then there's a problem of some sort that should be cleaned up.

First follow the options here:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/ISSUES.md

To summarize the steps for you, follow these:

```
# remove user-specific gems and git repos
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/

# remove system-wide git repos and git checkouts
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/

# remove project-specific settings and git repos
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached .gem files
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
rm -rf Gemfile.lock

# try to install one more time
bundle install
```

This will clear most any issues with your installation and give you a clean starting point to work from. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases when you have a "takes too long" problem with bundler you should specify your gem versions. Just saying `gem 'rspec'` won't do in some cases because the dependency tree will become impossible to solve quickly and then bundler will try out all possibilities before it comes up with a dependency tree and is able to get your gems. There was an official note on that bundler 1.1 problem but I can't find it right now.